# How do I add a number at the end of every line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have 23,000 lines, and I need to add the number `1` at the end of every line.

How can I do this?

Right now:

```
[line1]TEXT
[line2]TEXT
```

What I would want:

```
[line1]TEXT1
[line2]TEXT1
```

Comment: More interesting; how would you assign sequential numbers to sequential lines?  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Number the lines with the TextFX package (TextFx > TextFx Tools > Insert Line Numbers) and then move the line numbers to the EOL with a regexp.

Comment: If there is an empty line between 2 text lines, should that line also get a 1?

Comment: This kind of thing is what makes `sublime-text` so powerful, if you haven't used it. In sublime, it's just `ctrl+a` > `ctrl+shift+L` > `end` > You now have a uniform cursor at the end of every line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709869/how-to-paste-text-to-end-of-every-line-sublime-2

Comment: `:%s/$/1/`. Oh wait, that's [Vim](http://www.vim.org). ;-) (Which *is* available for Windows as well.)

Comment: @DevSolar Alternatively, `:g/$/norm A1`. Or the more complex but fancier `gg$<C-v>G$A1<esc>`. Or even the admittedly obnoxious `ggqqqqqA1<esc>j@qq@q`. More than one way to do it :P

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, use PowerShell: `$i=0; (gc example.txt) | % {$i++; "$($_)$i"} | sc example.txt`

Comment: For all the answers that are using regex with variations of `\r` and `\n`. Just use `\R` (upper case), it will [match unicode newline sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n/18992691#18992691). This means you won't have to bother about platform etc... You could then replace it with `1$0`. The only "small problem" I see is that the last line wouldn't get matched since there's no newline after it (End Of File). That's why I think using `$` is the best option in this case.

Comment: @dangph  ewww :-) .  I'm a confirmed bash fella,  but either way it's a question of setting up a "grep and replace" , so I appreciate the info.

Answer (score 30):

#### How do I add a number at the end of every line in Notepad++?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\r\n`
- Set "Replace with" to `1\r\n`
- Enable "Regular expression" or "Extended"

  Note - "Regular expression" is a superset of "Extended" so in this particular case it doesn't matter which one you use.
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

Notes:

- The above assumes you are editing a text file with Windows EOLs, `\r\n`.
- If you are using files with different EOLs you can convert them to Windows EOLs using Menu "Edit" > "EOL Conversion".
- If you aren't working with Windows EOL, and you don't wish to convert them, use the following instead:

  - Use `\n` instead of `\r\n` for Unix/OS X EOLs ("Find what" is `\n`, "Replace with" is `1\n`)
  - Use `\r` instead of `\r\n` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs ("Find what" is `\r`, "Replace with" is `1\r`)

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: This only works if the line delimiter is windows, \r\n.

Comment: Yes, but Notepad++ is a WIndows program ... ;)

Comment: Oh you're right ... :) Still, the text file could have other line ending coding ;)

Comment: Won't you need to manually add it to the last line (unless there's a blank line at the end)?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Probably  - I say probably because if the last line of text does have `\r\n` at the end the next line isn't really blank it is just "empty" ;)

Comment: If you aren't working with windows EOL, there is no reason to "convert" them... just use `\n` or `\r` instead (Unix and Mac EOLs respectively). `\n` => `1\n` or `\r` => `1\r`. I do this kinda stuff more often with Extended instead of Regex personally.

Comment: @WernerCD Should be noted that a single `\r` only applies to the defunct Mac OS. Not OS X, which uses `\n`.

Comment: Why "Regular expression" instead of "Extended" and why ". matches newline"?

Comment: You say that ". matches newline" is a required step. Why?

Comment: Upvoted because it doesn't need regex mode. "Extended" Search Mode should be enough.

Comment: @Bob I missed that memo, but as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3720674/409025) it does seem that newer Mac OSs (past 9) have switched to `\n` as opposed to `\r`. My main point stands: Assuming `\r\n` isn't wise. Not all files will go by that, despite being in a windows environment.

Comment: @DavidPostill Please pay attention to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3720674/409025) as Bob pointed out - the newline for "recent" OSx files is `\r` instead of `\n`. Those are the "standard" practices and need to be considered if using files from different sources.

Comment: @DavidPostill There are three line endings: Windows `\r\n`, Unix/NewMac `\r`, OldMac `\n`... just being pedantic here. The odds of editing a file with Old OSx linewrappings on a windows box is low... but you know what happens when you assume you won't ever do that :)

Comment: @WernerCD I'm just being pedantic as well. Unix/OSX is LF `\n`, MAC is CR '`\r`, Windows is CRLF `\r\n`. Your comment has Unix/OS and MAC **the wrong way around**. My answer is correct. Please read the notes at the end of the answer.

Comment: This doesn't need regex. Only extended

Comment: @exussum "Regular expression" is a superset of "extended" so in this particular case it doesn't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 19):

Another option is the record and playback feature.

1. With your cursor on the first line, Click on 'Start Recording'
2. Type <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>
3. Click on 'Stop Recording'
4. Click on 'Run a Macro Multiple Times...'
5. Select 'Run until the end of file' and click Run
6. Job done

**Screenshots**

[image: record and playback]

Type <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>

[image: Click on stop]

[image: Run Macro]

[image]

[image: Done]

Comment: Notepad++ macros never get enough love.

Answer (score 17):

**Updated answer:**

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> for opening the Replace Dialog.

Under search mode, tick Regular Expression.

`Find what:` $

`Replace with:` 1

And hit `Replace all`

---

**Original answer**

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> for opening the Replace Dialog.

Under search mode, tick `Regular Expression`.

Find what: `^.*$`

Replace with `($0)1`

And hit `Replace all`

**Explanation**

You are searching for the regular expression `^.*$`, which is esentially every line. `^` marks the beginning of a line, `.*` includes any character any number of times and `$` marks the end of the line. Thus, this regular expression finds all content on every line.

We replace this expression with `($0)1`, `$0` being the found expression, and appending a `1` to it.

Comment: Find = `$` and replace = `1` is sufficient.

Answer (score 10):

Or do it like the big boys do :).

Select the last column using Shift + Alt => right key (once) => down key (press till the last line).

Type whatever you want. It will appear on all lines at once.

Comment: I was going to say this as well .. why all the complex reg expresssion? this answers the question perfectly .. and why the down vote ? because somebody just didn't understand that it's a valid answer?  O.o

Comment: This may not be practical for 23,000 lines (too slow or otherwise (memory problems due to [Shlemiel the painter's algorithms](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)?)). Have you actually tried it on 23,000 lines?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Horrifically slow, but memory usage is fine (5 MB => 25 MB). The bigger issue is that it doesn't seem to cope well with differing line lengths.

Comment: @Ditto I make no claim to be an average user, but this seems considerably less intuitive than regular expressions. Then again, https://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: lol, yep .. I don't mind reg expressions, but I usually find things easier if there's another option ;)

Comment: This isn't a very good answer, first you would need to find the longest line, then you would need to press down till the last line, while testing this method I got bored after a couple dozen lines, I could not sit there for 20k+ lines

Comment: This answer is precisely based on the requirement of the original poster. Please look at what they have asked for. It is not mentioned that the strings are of variable length. So the premise was that they are fixed length strings. If you cannot sit there for 20k+, you can use Shift + PageDown and it will select to the end. I do not like to sit for 20k+ lines either. You have to decide if you want to spend time on finding a precise RegEx to do this or trade the time off with this technique. I have used this technique for 100k+ records with success, editor supports.

Answer (score 2):

**Extended Mode.**

I wanted to add a slightly different approach that's not mentioned in other answers: Extended Mode.

For something like this - where all you are concerned with are `\r`, `\n`, `\t` or others included in [this small list](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Searching_And_Replacing#Escape_sequences_supported_in_extended_mode) (although that page looks to be "dated", so not 100% sure on its veracity) there is no reason to go full out regular expression.

I use Notepad++'s extended mode "often" to massage file layouts - mainly centering around remove multiple empty lines, extra whitespace and other assorted oddities.

[image: Extended]

1. Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
2. Determine which [line endings you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720612/what-is-the-universal-newline-for-all-operating-systems-lf-and-cr/3720674#3720674)
3. In "Find What" put:

   - `\r\n` for Windows
   - `\r` for older versions of MacOS (9 or older)
   - `\n` for Unix or newer of MacOS (OS X or newer)
4. Set "Replace with" to

   - `1\r\n` for Windows
   - `1\r` for older versions of MacOS (9 or older)
   - `1\n` for Unix or newer of MacOS (OS X or newer)
5. Enable "Extended"
6. Click "Replace All"

Comment: "Regular expression" is a superset of "extended" so in this particular case is doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\n` for Unix and `\r` for older version of MacOS? First bullet from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Answer (score 1):

If it is equally long strings, then you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click and drag to block select and be able to write on several lines at the same time. If they are not equally long, but not space separated, you can't do the same procedure and then replace " " with "".

Comment: I sometimes use this feature, but dragging for 23,000 lines... Not so much fun :)

Answer (score 1):

**This way is lot easier in notepad++**

Steps -: 
1.Click end of first line.
2.Click ALT + C.
3.Fill what you want
4.Click ok.

Comment: This will only work if all lines are of same length.